# Suppose that $\iint_D f(x,y) dA=4$ where D is the disk $x^2+y^2≤16.$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Suppose that $\iint_D f(x,y) dA=4$ where D is the disk $x^2+y^2≤16$. Now suppose $E$ is the disk $x^2+y^2≤256$ and $g(x,y)=2f(\frac{x}{4},\frac{y}{4})$. What is the value of $\iint_E g(x,y) dA$?

I am stuck on this problem. My initial thoughts were that the second disc has double the radius the first disc is so it would be quadruple the answer for the first integral (so $16$) but that was incorrect, then i saw that both $x$ and $y$ were divided by $4$ so I divided $16$ by $4$ to get $4$ and that also didn't work. please help

Comment: Do you use $\mathrm dA=\mathrm d(x,y)$ ? In this case, the change of variables formula is helpful

Comment: Yes, you need to use the change of variables formula for a double integral. There's an obvious map suggested by the formula for $g(x,y)$ and by the fact that you want to send the disk of radius $4$ to the disk of radius $16$.

Comment: can you explain how to use change of variables in this question, I don't understand how to do it

Comment: Consider the transformation $\phi:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^2, (x,y)\mapsto (x/4,y/4)$